# zedGraph Barchart Bars Overlapping Issue

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am using zedGraph to plot BarCharts in C#. I am getting issues related with bar width when I try to plot large amount of data e.g. more than 5 years daily data. The Bars are becoming wider and overlapping. Is there any way to auto scaling the bar width to fit the pane?

Here is a code that I am trying:

```
        private void precipitationBHChart(ZedGraphControl zgc, DataTable dataTable) 
    {
        dataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Date";
        dataTable.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Precipitation";

        GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;

        //// set opposite axes major tic and minor tic
        myPane.XAxis.MajorTic.IsOpposite = false;
        myPane.XAxis.MinorTic.IsOpposite = false;
        myPane.YAxisList[0].MajorTic.IsOpposite = false;
        myPane.YAxisList[0].MinorTic.IsOpposite = false;

        // set xAxis type to date
        myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;

        // Disable zoom
        zgc.ZoomButtons = MouseButtons.None;
        zgc.ZoomButtons2 = MouseButtons.None;
        zgc.ZoomStepFraction = 0;

        // set xAxis scale min and max value
        object maxDate = dataTable.Compute("MAX(Date)", null);
        object minDate = dataTable.Compute("MIN(Date)", null);

        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = Convert.ToDateTime(maxDate).ToOADate();
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = Convert.ToDateTime(minDate).ToOADate();

        // Make up some data points from the Sine function
        PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            list1.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]).ToOADate(), Convert.ToDouble(dr[1]));
        }

        BarItem bar1 = myPane.AddBar("Precipitation", list1, Color.DarkGray);

        // Calculate the Axis Scale Ranges
        zgc.AxisChange();
    }
```

Here is sample chart:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8BnppTIW9YFczF4ZnlTLUJjOG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What are the myPane.BarSettings set to?

Comment: I've not defined myPane.BarSetting in my program. Can u suggest me about BarSetting??